# Display Logcat in Terminal?

Tags: android, terminal, logcat

**Edit/Solution:** execute `./adb logcat` in the platform-tools directory.

---

**Original Question:**

I know that there's a way to display the `LogCat` for an Android device/emulator in Terminal on my Mac, but I'm not sure what the command is.  This is mostly due to my incompetence with UNIX commands.

Here are my previous failures:

> adb logcat
>   adb.exe logcat
>   FULL_PATH_TO_PLATFORM_TOOLS/adb logcat
>   FULL_PATH_TO_PLATFORM_TOOLS/adb.exe logcat

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Ah, just `adb logcat` should work. You may need to do an explicit path if the Android SDK tools directories aren't in your PATH, but that should do it.

Comment: I'm getting: "-bash: adb: command not found".  I'm really novice with this, so what should I do?

Comment: You'll need to specify the full path to adb: which folder did you install the SDK to?

Comment: cd to the folder, then run `adb logcat`. Alternatively, put it on your path.

Comment: Try something like `/User/csadmin/downloads/android-sdk-mac/platform-tools/adb logcat`.

Comment: adb is in <sdk_folder>/platform-tools on my machine.

Comment: I'm in platform-tools, I clearly see 'adb' when I 'ls', yet I'm **still** getting the error!

Comment: If you are in platform-tools, you have to do `./adb logcat`.

Comment: The ./adb logcat was very helpful!

Comment: the .adb logcat was helpful

Answer (score 7):

If you have NPM, you could install module:

```
$ npm install -g logcat
```

that will provide you to start monitoring colored logcat in console and //127.0.0.1/.

```
$ logcat
```

[Here](https://github.com/spirinvladimir/logcat) is description

Comment: What else do you have to do to make it work? I get an error. $ logcat
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:80

Comment: Does your 80 port free for new web service? You can change port to other.

Comment: use **sudo logcat** as < 1000 ports are reserved and only root or system can use them

Answer (score 0):

In Terminal Emulator:

```
logcat > /sdcard/logfile.txt
```

This will put the logcat content in `/sdcard/logfile.txt` (your sd card main directory) obviously.
[Source](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/wiki/Logcat) (with more ways to acquire logcat):

Comment: Or `adb logcat >> mylog` from Linux (not Android) command prompt.