# How can I see my debug logs on Unity Android?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'm still new to `Android` development and I'm currently having difficulties trying to figure out how to debug my `Unity` game when I deploy it to my Android device. I need to see what is happening while the user is playing my game to make sure my code logic is flowing as expected.

I'm coming from an `iOS` background and in `iOS`, I simply have to build my Unity project and open and run it in `Xcode`. `Xcode` automatically shows a debug window where I can see my `Debug.Log` messages I have set in my `C#` scripts in Unity.

How do I do debug on the Android platform? I have tried following liortal's answer [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/760964/how-to-debug-an-android-application-in-monodevelop.html) but I can't seem to get it to work even with the following settings suggested.

I'm using `Unity5` and I already have `Developer` options and `USB debugging` enabled on my Android device by the way.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **logcat**.  You'll find it at sdk\tools or sdk\platform-tools.

Then you can use it like this:

```
adb logcat # (start logging)
adb logcat -c # (clears the log)
adb logcat > dump.txt # (dump log info)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm using OS X so I opened a terminal on the `platform-tools` folder and I typed `adb logcat` but I am getting a `command not found`. Any ideas?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7601178/display-logcat-in-terminal

Comment: oh rookie mistake since I don't know much on how to use Terminal. Thanks I got it working now!